# How to restrict folder content listing in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a web application developed in PHP.
My requirement is to block a folder which contains uploaded documents.
For example, if a user click a document link on the application, it should open
http://localhost:1987/enterprise_resource_planning/uploads/students/documents/1499866795_100_100.pdf
if a user execute below url, it should block
http://localhost:1987/enterprise_resource_planning/uploads/students/documents/
I've tried .htaccess with Deny from all, but it is blocking everything.
Any solution for this senario ?

Comment: `deny from all` - well that would be why it blocks everything, you need to set your server files and folders to certain permisisons and user groups as well as using htaccess for restriction - but not using deny from all

Comment: you mean, you do not want to see a listing of all files?

Comment: Maybe a `.htaccess` in that folder that contains `Options -Indexes`

Comment: Yes exactly. I dont want to see a listing on web browser if I execute
http://localhost:1987/enterprise_resource_planning/uploads/students/documents/

Comment: The only way for this to be php-related is if you create a `index.php` in the uploaded files folder.

Comment: I am using WAMP server

Comment: Avoid the use of .htaccess files and configure your virtual hosts instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible solutions:

- place a file index.html or index.php in the directory
- define in your httpd.conf `Options -Indexes`
- place that line in .htaccess

personnally I prefer the 2nd line. There hardly ever is use for automatical listing of the files to a browsing visitor.